# Object serializable for AJAX, WCF and ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, serialization

consider the following class and struct

```
public class Entity {
    public IdType Id {get;set;}
    public string Data {get;set;}
}

[TypeConverter(IdTypeConverter))]
public struct IdType {
    ... any data ...
}
```

The IdTypeConverter can convert the IdType struct from and to string.

Now, what I want is this class to be serializable for AJAX, WCF and ViewState. The senario could be a WCF web service which provides as array of Entity[] to a DataSource. And a custom control which binds to the datasource, saves this class to it's ViewState and sends the data to client side code.

This could be achieved easily by simply adding a [Serializable] attribute to all serialized types. But I don't want the IdType to be serialized, but to be converted to a string. Thus the JSON representation should be

```
{ 'Id'=>'StringRepresentationOfId', 'Data'=>'foo' }
```

This would analogously be the optimal serialization for WCF and ViewState.

Another solution would be to write another class

```
public class JsonEntity {
    public JsonEntity(Entity from) {
        Id = from.Id;
        Data = from.Data;
    }
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

and use this for JsonSerialization. But I don't like this, because this would imply that the control which is sending the data to the client knows about the Entity type.

The actual question is: Is it possible to customize JsonSerialization with attributes without breaking WCF and ViewState serialization?

EDIT:
An answer like "That' impossible" would satify me, since I'd stop trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read, the LosFormatter class used for ViewState serialization checks if there is a TypeConverter for a given object and uses it, so you should be covered there.

[This article](http://nayyeri.net/custom-json-serialization-in-asp-net-ajax) describes how to create your own JavaScriptConverter to perform custom serialization.  The Serialize method that you have to implement returns `IDictionary<string, object>`, so you might have to create a JavaScriptConverter class for your Entity class rather than for your IdType struct.  Below is an example, though I haven't had a chance to test it out:

Note: the examples in my post just look up the associated TypeConverter for IdType in order to convert it to a string, but unless there's a specific reason to do it that way you might as well just call a specific function (e.g. override ToString) that returns a the string representation directly instead of looking up the TypeConverter as my example code is doing.

```
public class EntityJsonConverter : System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

        Entity entity = obj as Entity;
        if (entity != null)
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            TypeConverter idTypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(entity.Id);
            if (idTypeConverter != null)
            {
                if (idTypeConverter.CanConvertTo(typeof(string)))
                    values.Add("Id", idTypeConverter.ConvertTo(entity.Id, typeof(string)));
                else
                    throw new SerializationException(string.Format("The TypeConverter for type \"{0}\" cannot convert to string.", this.GetType().FullName));
            }
            else
                throw new SerializationException(string.Format("Unable to find a TypeConverter for type \"{0}\".", this.GetType().FullName));

            values.Add("Data", serializer.Serialize(entity.Data));

            return values;
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Expected argument of type \"{0}\", but received \"{1}\".", typeof(Entity).FullName, obj.GetType().FullName), "obj");
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { yield return typeof(Entity); }
    }
}
```

If you also want the behavior that you described for XML serialization, you could have the IdType struct implement the IXmlSerializable interface.  Below is an example of a WriteXml method implementation that uses the TypeConverter defined for the IdType struct:

```
    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this);
        if (converter != null)
        {
            if (converter.CanConvertTo(typeof(string)))
                writer.WriteString(converter.ConvertTo(this, typeof(string)) as string);
            else
                throw new SerializationException(string.Format("The TypeConverter for type \"{0}\" cannot convert to string.", this.GetType().FullName));
        }
        else
            throw new SerializationException(string.Format("Unable to find a TypeConverter for type \"{0}\".", this.GetType().FullName));
    }
```

Comment: This JavaScriptConverter type looks nice. Is there an attribute which tells the JsonSerializer to use a custom JavaScriptConverter?

Comment: I don't think there is an attribute for that, but check out the article at http://nayyeri.net/custom-json-serialization-in-asp-net-ajax.  It shows how to register the JavaScriptConverter in a config file.  I haven't had a chance to verify any of that, though.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution similar to creating a proxy class just for serialization would be using the `[NonSerialized()]` attribute.

IdType could be non-serializable and another serializable string property could be implemented as a proxy (which would - on get or set - assign to / read from the IdType).

The solution could even look elegant with the use of aspect-oriented programming.

Comment: Sure! So far this is the only solution which solves the json part,  avoiding that the control, which serializes the data, has to know about the type at compile time. Though I don't like extra public fields on my data entities.